# How to make posed model stay in place in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, pose-mode

How can I make the model stay in posed postion while ive use edit mode?
Because when ive loaded saved pose, and use edit mode mode model return to default standing pose.
[image: P]
I have noticed this problem when my model seats so ive wanted fix it
but it is not visible in default standing pose.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to enable the *On Cage* option in the *Armature* modifier. It has a downside though, if you select a vertex, the *Move* gizmo won't stick to the vertex pose position but to its rest position. It would make more sense that once you enable *On Cage*, the gizmo sticks to the vertex pose position.

[image]

Comment: It worked thanks
 but how restore it?

Comment: what do you mean by restore?

Comment: model stays in seat pose while bones are in default pose postion.